# Google Spreadsheet IF formula

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have three columns in my table: column G - maturity date, column H - payment date and column I - number of days between maturity date and today `IF(G11="";"";G11-today())`.

What I need to do is to make cells in column I not display anything until I enter data in G cells, make column I cells show the number of days to due date when column G contains data, and also make column I cells display "paid" when I enter data in column H.

I tried this:

```
=IF(AND(G11=""&H11="");"";IF(AND(G11=">0"&H11="");"G11-E1";IF(AND(G11=">0"&H11=">0");"paid")))
```

but the formula doesn't work as its gives me TRUTH OF FALSE instead of what I want.

Comment: Some example data with a clear outline of the expected result would be welcomed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your requirement but your formula is full of syntax errors so the following might at least help:

```
=IF(AND(G11="",H11=""),"",IF(AND(G11>=0,H11=""),G11-E$1,IF(AND(G11>=0,H11>0),"paid")))
```

Comment: Thank You!! pnuts, it`s working perfect :) I just had to replace "," with ";" and it does what I need. Thank You one more time